# ASP WebForms AutoCompleteExtender in GridView not firing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have this webform with 3 AutoCompleteExtenders using the AjaxControlToolkit. The first one deals with customers from a database and that works very well. I have place 2 others in a gridview, AutoCompleteExtenders 2 and 3 to fetch items. For some reason, these do not work and a breakpoint in Items.asmx does not reach when running the code. I have setup these 2 extenders same as the customer one.

What am I doing wrong? I have searched articles online on use in gridviews but am unable to find the issue.

I have

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
```

in the masterpage.

**Code in webform:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="PipemanWebPortal.Views.PurchaseOrders.Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Add Purchase Order</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $(".alert").fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }, 3000);
        });

        // On Page Load
        $(function () {
            SetDatePicker();
        });
        // On UpdatePanel Refresh
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        if (prm != null) {
            prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
                if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                    SetDatePicker();
                    $(".datepicker-orient-bottom").hide();
                }
            });
        };

        function SetDatePicker() {
            $('#datetimepicker').datepicker
                ({
                    format: 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                    inline: true,
                    todayHighlight: true,
                    autoclose: true
                });
        }
    </script>
    <div runat="server" visible="false" id="AlertDanger" class="alert alert-danger">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>You must choose a date</strong>
    </div>
    <div runat="server" visible="false" id="AlertSuccess" class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>Purchase requisition saved successfully</strong>
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="PODetails" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelPO" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#E6E6E6">
                        <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-6 control-label">Required Date</asp:Label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRequiredDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRequiredDate" Display="Dynamic"
                                                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Required Date field is required." />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-6 control-label">No.</asp:Label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDocNum" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-6 control-label" class="">Cust. PO No.</asp:Label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPurchaseOrderNo" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPurchaseOrderNo" Display="Dynamic"
                                                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Cust. Purchase Order No field is required." />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-6 control-label">Contact</asp:Label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtContact" Display="Dynamic"
                                                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Contact field is required." />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-12 control-label" class="">Customer Name</asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-9">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
                                        ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
                                        runat="server"
                                        TargetControlID="txtCustomer"
                                        ServicePath="../../Web_Service/Customers.asmx"
                                        ServiceMethod="GetCustomers"
                                        MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                        EnableCaching="true"
                                        CompletionSetCount="10"
                                        CompletionInterval="10"
                                        DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
                                        ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCustomer" Display="Dynamic"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Customer field is required." />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:GridView ID="pOGridView"
                        runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        AllowPaging="True"
                        AllowSorting="True"
                        ShowFooter="True"
                        OnRowEditing="pOGridView_RowEditing"
                        OnRowUpdating="pOGridView_RowUpdating"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="pOGridView_PageIndexChanging"
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="pOGridView_RowCancelingEdit"
                        PagerStyle-CssClass="bs-pagination"
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
                        EmptyDataText="No Records Found"
                        CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="#">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLineNum" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="120px" HeaderText="Item">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblItem" runat="server"
                                        Text='<%# Bind("Item")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server" Width="300px" Text='<%# Bind("Item")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
                                        ID="AutoCompleteExtender2"
                                        runat="server"
                                        TargetControlID="txtItem"
                                        ServicePath="../../Web_Service/Items.asmx"
                                        ServiceMethod="GetItems"
                                        MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                        EnableCaching="true"
                                        CompletionSetCount="10"
                                        CompletionInterval="10"
                                        DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
                                        ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtItem" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edit"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Item field is required." />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
                                        ID="AutoCompleteExtender3"
                                        runat="server"
                                        TargetControlID="txtItem"
                                        ServicePath="../../Web_Service/Items.asmx"
                                        ServiceMethod="GetItems"
                                        MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                                        EnableCaching="true"
                                        CompletionSetCount="10"
                                        CompletionInterval="10"
                                        DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
                                        ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtItem" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Insert"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" InitialValue="-1" ErrorMessage="The Item field is required." />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="60px" HeaderText="Qty.">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server"
                                        Text='<%# Bind("Quantity")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Width="100px"
                                        Text='<%# Bind("Quantity")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edit"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Quantity field is required." />
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic"
                                        ErrorMessage="Only integers allowed." ValidationExpression="^(0|[1-9]\d*)$"
                                        ValidationGroup="Edit"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Insert"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Quantity field is required." />
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic"
                                        ErrorMessage="Only integers allowed." ValidationExpression="^(0|[1-9]\d*)$"
                                        ValidationGroup="Insert"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Unit Price">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblUnitPrice" runat="server"
                                        Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" Width="100px"
                                        Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUnitPrice" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edit"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Unit Price is required." />
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic"
                                        ErrorMessage="Only numbers allowed." ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{0,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"
                                        ValidationGroup="Edit"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUnitPrice" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Insert"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Unit Price is required." />
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtUnitPrice" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic"
                                        ErrorMessage="Only numbers allowed." ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{0,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"
                                        ValidationGroup="Insert"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Order Price">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblOrderPrice" runat="server"
                                        Text='<%# Bind("OrderPrice")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrderPrice" runat="server" Width="100px"
                                        Text='<%# Bind("OrderPrice")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtOrderPrice" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Edit"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Order Price is required." />
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtOrderPrice" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic"
                                        ErrorMessage="Only numbers allowed." ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{0,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"
                                        ValidationGroup="Edit"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrderPrice" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUnitPrice" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Insert"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Order Price is required." />
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtOrderPrice" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Display="Dynamic"
                                        ErrorMessage="Only numbers allowed." ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{0,6}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"
                                        ValidationGroup="Insert"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ValidationGroup="Edit" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server"
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Bind("LineNum")%>'
                                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')"
                                        Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteRowPurchaseOrder"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="Insert" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                        OnClick="AddRowPurchaseOrder" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="InsertButton" OnClick="Insert" Text="Insert" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-primary" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="CancelButton" OnClick="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the other two AutoCompleteExtender are on two different `<asp:Panel>`, try put on same Panel,
 `<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#E6E6E6">`. that's probably the reason why the first one is working, and other two are not.